# Publish compiled Flex application and other resources to directory in Maven?

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2, flexmojos

I just got all set up and compiling in Maven with Flex-Mojos, and now my next question is how I would "publish" my compiled application to an arbitrary directory along with its web resources. It has a few PHP scripts which need to be copied, as well as the html wrapper of course. If I were to do this in Ant (which is where I'm coming from), I would do the following:

```
<copy todir="${deploy.dir}">
    <fileset file="${compiled.swf.file}"/>
    <fileset dir="${web.dir}" includes="**/*"/>
</copy>
```

Since this is Maven and the  approach to project management is very different, what should I do to accomplish this? I need a fairly easy way to test my application (not unit-test, mind you) in a browser, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the Maven Ant runner to do it in the `copy-resources` phase.

Answer (score 1):

On my project, I have the HTML wrapper file in a war project under src/main/resources. Then I used the [Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to copy the SWF to the WAR. Here's an example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack-swf</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>              
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/<your-project-name></outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Here's an example dependency:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId><your-swf-artifact></artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>swf</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How would I copy my resources in main/resources to the output directory? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Good question. Files in src/main/resources will get copied automatically to that directory, assuming that <your-project-name> matches build.finalName in your pom.xml. See this [link](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/web-sect-creating-project.html) for an example of a WAR pom.xml. Maven is all about convention over configuration. That means that by default files in src/main/resources should be copied automatically to that location. Then Maven zips up that output directory into the WAR file and you can deploy that WAR on your server.

Comment: <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>. But yeah, it's better to keep maven convention